# Flutter App crashes on Android for Anonymous Sign In with Firebase Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

As the title says, I'm trying to set up anonymous sign in using Firebase firestore for my Flutter app, but it crashes on Android. It works perfectly fine on iOS.

I set up Firebase for my app using the wizard found in the firebase console, and used all the suggested version numbers when configuring the android app.

My dependencies in the android/build.gradle file are as follows:

```js
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    }
```

And in the android/app/build.gradle file the following is set:

minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 28

I also downloaded and placed the google-services.json file into the path android/app

I know I'm connected to Firebase because I set up google analytics and I can see myself as an active user in the analytics panel

This is my set up for the anonymous sign in:

In the "auth.dart" file:

```js
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class AuthService {
      // this instance allows us to communicate with Firebase in the backend
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  // sign in anon
  Future signInAnon() async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      return user;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

and in the SignIn widget, where I use a button that calls the anonSignIn method:

```js
GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () async {
                    dynamic result = await _auth.signInAnon();
                    if (result == null) {
                      print('error signing in');
                    } else {
                      print('anon user signed in');
                      print(result);
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'Skip for now >',
                    style: TextStyle(color: eigthColor),
                  ),
                ),
```

The app prints the right results for iOS in the debug console, but when running on Android, both the emulator and on a real device (Samsung), the app quits when the button is pressed and all that is shown in the debug console is below. I'm a development noob. Please help!

**
W/BiChannelGoogleApi(11081): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzak@c8b9c14
E/AndroidRuntime(11081): Process: com.tsf.freshee_scratch, PID: 11081
E/AndroidRuntime(11081): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/ArrayMap;
E/AndroidRuntime(11081):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzc(Unknown Source:22)
E/AndroidRuntime(11081):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzde(Unknown Source:17)
E/AndroidRuntime(11081):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzdd(Unknown Source:8)
E/AndroidRuntime(11081):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzan.zzdf(Unknown Source:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(11081):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzm.isAnonymous(Unknown Source:47)
E/AndroidRuntime(11081):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzat.zzi(Unknown Source:57)
E/AndroidRuntime(11081):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzat.zzg(Unknown Source:10)
E/AndroidRuntime(11081):    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zza(Unknown Source:62)
E/AndroidRuntime(11081):    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$zzb.zza(Unknown Source:5)
E/AndroidRuntime(11081):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzcl.zzdx(Unknown Source:13)
E/AndroidRuntime(11081):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzen.zzen(Unknown Source:35)
E/AndroidRuntime(11081):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzen.zza(Unknown Source:41)
E/AndroidRuntime(11081):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzep.zza(Unknown Source:9)
E/AndroidRuntime(11081):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdx.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source:9)
E/AndroidRuntime(11081):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zza.onTransact(Unknown Source:13)
E/AndroidRuntime(11081):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:739)
E/AndroidRuntime(11081): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.tsf.freshee_scratch-RyjASMTcDx7DTMAHwjdqeg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.tsf.freshee_scratch-RyjASMTcDx7DTMAHwjdqeg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.tsf.freshee_scratch-RyjASMTcDx7DTMAHwjdqeg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(11081):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
E/AndroidRuntime(11081):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime(11081):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime(11081):    ... 16 more
D/ViewRootImpl@c13a6a1MainActivity: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
D/InputMethodManager(11081): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@5990a33[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(11081): getNavigationBarColor() -352319669
I/Process (11081): Sending signal. PID: 11081 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
**